# Error while creating One Note file in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, template, onenote

When I try to create a OneNote file in a Document Library by clicking on 'New Document', it gives me this error message "Invalid template Type 4"

[image]

[image]

The below are the errors from ULS log:

**1.** Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry.

**2.** Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domainName\userName, ClaimsCount=118

**3.** UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.

**4.** Application error when access /_layouts/15/CreateNewDocument.aspx, Error=Invalid template type 4.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.CreateNewDocument.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

**5.** Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Invalid template type 4.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.CreateNewDocument.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

**6.** Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Invalid template type 4.

Comment: Does this error happen on all document libraries?  Do any other document types work (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).  Is your Office Web Apps Server set up to allow the editing of documents?

Comment: Yes, this error happens on all document libraries across all the site collections. And yes, Word, Excel and PowerPoint are working fine. Though I don't have license to edit the documents with web app, it is creating a Word, Excel or PowerPoint file giving me error message that you don't have license but it is creating the document anyway. But in case of OneNote, it gives me error.

Comment: Can you give us the specific errors from the ULS log?  Please only include the specific errors that correspond to the correlation id in the log.

Comment: @JamesGrizzle I have added the ULS error logs in the question.

Comment: @JamesGrizzle Any help here ?

Comment: Is OWA hooked up to any other services like Outlook or Skype?  If so, does OneNote work from those other apps?  If not, it is likely a problem with OWA, not SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the Site Notebook site feature on a test site and try again.

[image: One Note notebook feature]

Comment: Tried this. Not able to activate the feature.

Comment: What happens?  What is the error message? Also do you see any errors in the ULS log when you activate the feature?